# XQuery: Create a new element with a given name?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have data like:

```
    <td>USERID</td>

    <td>NAME</td>

    <td>RATING</td>
```

I want to transform it into:

```
<userid></userid>
<name></name>
<rating></rating>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a [**computed element constructor**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-3/#id-computedElements) to generate an element with the `lower-case` value of the `text` nodes for each of the `td` elements.

> A **computed element constructor**
>   creates an element node, allowing both
>   the name and the content of the node
>   to be computed.

For the sake of the example, assuming that your XML is in a file called **foo.xml**, you could do something like this:

```
<doc>
{
for $name in doc('foo.xml')//td/text()
return element {lower-case($name)} {''}
}
</doc>
```

to produce this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
 <userid/>
 <name/>
 <rating/>
</doc>
```

You could also evaluate the `lower-case()` function as part of the **XPATH** expression instead of the element constructor, like this:

```
<doc>
{
for $name in doc('foo.xml')//td/text()/lower-case(.)
return element {$name} {''}
}
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return <doc>{
for $d in $doc/element()/text()
return element{fn:lower-case($d)} {}}</doc>
```

where $doc stores the Xml.