# Creating namespace free Element in xquery

Tags: namespaces, xquery

I have created an element as mentioned here [XQuery: Create a new element with a given name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542235/xquery-create-a-new-element-with-a-given-name/13659973#13659973).

The code for creating element is below

```
declare function local:remove-tag-if-empty($elem as element(), $name as xs:string)
{
if(not($elem/node()))
then ()
else
(
element {$name} {$elem/text()}
)
};
```

Now what I am getting from the generated XML is something like this (I am using the above function to create DOB tag)

```
<DOB xmlns = "">2012-10-14+03:00</DOB>
```

I don't `want xmlns=""` to be the part of the generated xml. Can anyone tell me that how to create element without namespace? Thanks in advance.

Comment: <DOB xmlns = "">2012-10-14+03:00</DOB>. This is what I meant. In the original question the editor has replaced the DOB tags.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example? This may also be helpful for other viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create:

> <DOB>2012-10-14+03:00</DOB>

It is functionally the same as below:

> <DOB xmlns="">2012-10-14+03:00</DOB>

Comment: Because when I receive the request (JAX-WS) gives me namespaces issues. Yes I know the functionality is the same but I don't want to create it on the first place. Is it possible?